# can List<Character> be instantiated?

Tags: java

when I write this, it has the error "cannot instantiate the type List < Character>"

```
Character[] ray = {'a','s','e'};
List<Character> l = new List<Character>(Arrays.asList(ray));
```

But when I write this, there is no error

```
Character[] ray = {'a','s','e'};
List<Character> l = Arrays.asList(ray);
```

So why is that?

edit: and what is the type of l in the second example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) (it defines some methods, but doesn't implement them). Try using a class that implements it, like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

```
List<Character> l = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(ray));
```

Comment: so why in the second example I have no error? what is the type of l then?

Comment: @nubhihi219 You can cast an ArrayList to List (`List x = new ArrayList()`), you just can't directly instantiate a List (`new List()`). I suspect `Arrays.asList()` creates an ArrayList, then passes the result to you as a List.

Comment: @BrendanLong Great explanation, but one nit: <pedantry> `Arrays.asList()` creates a "wrapper" around its parameter array rather than creating a proper `ArrayList`. There are a few differences, perhaps the most important of which being that (a) updates to the resulting list update the given array; and (b) you can't add or remove elements from such a `List`, only update existing elements. Unfortunately the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) isn't as clear as it could be. </pedantry> :)

Comment: @Brendan Long: List is an interface, so I can't instantiate it, I understand. But why can I cast ArrayList to List? 

Is that a property of interfaces that it is able to cast an object of a class which implements a certain interface to that interface?

Comment: @nubhihi219 The whole point of interface is that you can treat everything that implements them the same, which is implemented in the language by allow you to cast classes that implement an interface to that interface. In the case of List, ArrayList and LinkedList both implement List, and the reason that that's useful is that you can return a List and the person calling your function doesn't need to know whether it's an ArrayList or a LinkedList (or anything else that implements List). This lets you change how something works internally without breaking things for people using your code.